# Вывод подстроки в egrep

Tags: регулярные-выражения, bash, grep

Как получить на выходе не всё совпадение, а только ту часть, которая в скобках (значение value)?

```
egrep "name=\"_csrf_token\" value=\"(.*?)\"" tmp11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

используйте опцию `-o`:

```
$ ls / | grep '.*e'
dev
etc
home
media
$ ls / | grep -o '.*e'
de
e
home
me
```

дополнительное чтение:

```
$ man grep
```

---

если же нужна только часть найденного, то лучше воспользоваться другими средствами. например, программой `sed`:

```
$ sed -rn 's/.*name="_csrf_token" value="([0-9]+)".*/\1/p' файл
123456
```

дополнительное чтение (должна быть установлена программа `info`, что иногда не делают дистрибьюторы):

```
$ info sed
```

Comment: Не совсем так. Допустим в файле есть строка `name="_csrf_token" value="123456"`. Мне нужно достать оттуда `123456`. Т.е. мне нужна только часть найденной строки.

Comment: @Artem, я дополнил ответ.